# how to benchmark parts within a function?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have one complicated function that is doing three different things. I have a benchmark written to evaluate the performance of this function, but I want to know the performance of each thing happening within the function separately. Until now, I am using `Instant::now() + printing` to measure the performance. But is there another way to do it?

Comment: Perhaps the obvious question: why not split your complicated function into three different functions so you can test the steps independently?

Comment: @kmdreko I want to calculate things like if I run all these together, how much time each step takes

Comment: That is, you want to run a benchmark which will execute the whole code, but measure only part of it?

Comment: @Cerberus yes can think that was

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`criterion`](https://github.com/bheisler/criterion.rs) for that. This crate offers a functionality to measure the execution time yourself with [Custom Measurements](https://bheisler.github.io/criterion.rs/book/user_guide/custom_measurements.html).

Here is a basic usage example:

```rust
c.bench_function("middle part", |b| {
        b.iter_custom(|iters| {
            let mut exec_time = Duration::ZERO;

            for i in 0..iters {
                // First part of function
                let start = Instant::now();
                // Middle part of function (which is measured here)
                exec_time += start.elapsed();
                // Last part of function
            }
            exec_time
        });
    });
```

Obviously you can then switch this up to also benchmark the first and last part of your function.